# Context API using the initial value not the one set in UseState

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-context

I just started using typescript with react and tried to deal with ContextAPI with the typescript.
So Far I've set a context and tried to use a provider inside my app.tsx.
My context file is looking like this:

```
import { createContext, ReactNode, useState } from "react";

type props = {
 children: ReactNode
}

type GlobalContextType = {
  currentValue: number;
  setCurrentValue: (value: number) => void;
}

const INITIAL_VALUE = {
  currentValue: 1,
  setCurrentValue: () => {},
}

export const GlobalContext = createContext<GlobalContextType>(INITIAL_VALUE); 

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }: props) => {
  const [currentValue, setCurrentValue] = useState(3);

  return(
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={{ currentValue, setCurrentValue }}>
      { children }
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

while my app.tsx file is looking like this:

```
import './App.css';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { GlobalContext, GlobalProvider } from './ContextAPI/GlobalContext';


function App() {
  const { currentValue, setCurrentValue } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  return (
    <GlobalProvider>
      <h1>{ currentValue }</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCurrentValue(currentValue + 1)}>Increment</button>
    </GlobalProvider>
  );

}

export default App;
```

There are few things that didn't work as I expected.
First: when I go to my localhost page it displays the inital value, which is 1, not the
one that I set using useState(3).
Second: When I click the button, it doesn't update the value.

I imagine that I'm always using the initial state value and not the one that I'm trying to set inside the provider.

Comment: Your context provider needs to be higher up the component tree than the consumer. Ie, `<GlobalProvider`> needs to be a parent component of `<App>`. You have it the other way around.

Comment: Oh, i see! I thought that the <GlobalProvider> being parent of the elements inside the App was enough! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the function increment in the context API then call it in the app right just after onClick event